# Breeze.js - Querying Big Data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

### TL : DR - Using Big Data w/ Breeze.js

I haven't found the most elegant way to do this yet, looking for anyone with some good experience querying big data and still controlling cache -

If I go out and hit the server and let's say I get 20k records back, each with an Id and a name property.  Because I want to utilize my cache when interacting with that data set I cache the data and do stuff with it.

Then say I want to look at a new set of data, but not lose all of my navigation properties so I go out, hit the server, add more entities to the cache, and then because I like to look at my data I do a select query to get POJO's to shove in the grid.

The first time I hit the server and cache those records it doesn't matter that I don't apply any filters to local cache.  The second time, however, my cache now potentially contains twice the number of entities that I want to be working with.

Again, I don't want to do a lot of complex filtering on the data, that's what the server is for.

### The problem

I can't just hit my local cache anymore without using the same query params, which is not possible (or within reason)

Since I am using Knockout.js for data-binding I need to use a select query on the data after it is returned to get POJO's (ko.toJS() will not flatten the navigation properties, ko.toJSON() doesn't work on Breeze entities because it thinks they are recursive)

### The half-way solution

I could create a copy of my entityManager, go out and get the nav properties again, and then requery the data, but then I am having to do a lot of extra queries

### What I would like to do

Obliterate the cache for that one entity type so when I refill it with new entities I can grab that data to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official method for clearing the cache of a particular entity type. You could do this

```
manager.getEntities('Foo').forEach(function(foo) {manager.detachEntity(foo);});
```

That's a subtractive approach. You could look at an additive approach if you knew what the related types were and thought it would be faster to start with a fresh manager and add the related types rather than blast away at the type you wanted to kill.

I don't think that's what you really want to do so I'll just write the pseudocode for it.

- extract the related types: `var related = manager.getEntities(['a', 'b', 'c']);`. You'd only have to do this once; use `related` again and again thereafter.
- clear the manager before the next query: `manager.clear();`
- attach the related entities: `related.forEach(function(entity){manager.attachEntity(entity);});`
- perform your next 'foo' query.

I have no idea which approach is better for your application.

You could propose (in User Voice) a new EntityManager method that clears the cache of a single type (or array of types). Perhaps optional parameters to the `EntityManager.clear()` method. We have such a thing in DevForce.

Answer (score -1):

this is not a complete solution, but to json your data, use this:

ko.mapping.toJS(data, { ignore: ['entityAspect', 'entityType'] })

Comment: You obviously didn't read my question where I explicitly stated toJS isn't going to work and why